# Enable Datepicker in a WooCommerce Checkout custom text field

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, datepicker

In WooCommerce, I can get a field hooked into my WooCommerce cart page & showing up OK using the following in my theme's (Storefront) functions PHP:

```
<?
            // ADD Custom Fields to Checkout Page
            /**
             * Add the field to the checkout
             **/

            add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field');

            function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

                date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
                $mydateoptions = array('' => __('Select PickupDate', 'woocommerce' )); 

                echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h3>'.__('Delivery Info').'</h3>';

               woocommerce_form_field( 'order_pickup_date', array(
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
                    'id'            => 'datepicker',
                    'required'      => true,
                    'label'         => __('Delivery Date'),
                    'placeholder'       => __('Select Date'),
                    'options'     =>   $mydateoptions
                    ),$checkout->get_value( 'order_pickup_date' ));

                echo '</div>';
            }

            /**
             * Process the checkout
             **/
            add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

            function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
                global $woocommerce;

                // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
                if (!$_POST['order_pickup_date'])
                     wc_add_notice( '<strong>PickupDate</strong> ' . __( 'is a required field.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            }

            /**
             * Update the order meta with field value
             **/
            add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');

            function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
                if ($_POST['order_pickup_date']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'PickupDate', esc_attr($_POST['order_pickup_date']));
            }
            ?>
```

However, the datepicker widget is not initiated when you click into the field. I know the following code is required in the header for JQuery to work:

```
<script>
$( function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); } );
</script>
```

This did not work for me, so I thought to put this function into the checkout.js file in Storefront theme, but the added field didn't have calendar widget functionality.

There's a lot of `.js` in the them do I need to start a new one for includes?

Comment: Are you getting any errors, check console logs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you will need to:

- Enqueu main jquery-ui datepicker script
- Change your custom script starting it with `jQuery(function($){` instead of `$(function(){` …

So to enable **`datepicker`** for your custom text field your code will be:

```
// Register main datepicker jQuery plugin script
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enabling_date_picker' );
function enabling_date_picker() {

    // Only on front-end and checkout page
    if( is_admin() || ! is_checkout() ) return;

    // Load the datepicker jQuery-ui plugin script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
}

// Call datepicker functionality in your custom text field
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field', 10, 1);
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    $mydateoptions = array('' => __('Select PickupDate', 'woocommerce' ));

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">
    <h3>'.__('Delivery Info').'</h3>';

    // YOUR SCRIPT HERE BELOW 
    echo '
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>';

   woocommerce_form_field( 'order_pickup_date', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'id'            => 'datepicker',
        'required'      => true,
        'label'         => __('Delivery Date'),
        'placeholder'       => __('Select Date'),
        'options'     =>   $mydateoptions
        ),$checkout->get_value( 'order_pickup_date' ));

    echo '</div>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works. On storefront theme you will get that:

[image]

> You may need to style it…

Answer (score 3):

Just an update that this is no longer necessary. With Woocommerce you can simply change the style to 'date' and it deals with the rest for you - yahoo!

Comment: As @shaneonabike mentioned, when you call `woocommerce_form_field()`, pass in `'type' => 'date'`, since this is a supported field type: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-template-functions.html#source-view.2812