# Choosing a date and time after choosing the WooCommerce delivery method

Tags: php, jquery, datetime, woocommerce, checkout

I need to make a selection of the time and date of delivery of the products, after choosing the method of delivery and place these fields in `woocommerce_after_shipping_rate`.

As I see it. The customer chooses the delivery method, for example, "Courier".

After that, two checkboxes appear:

1. ASAP
2. Delivery Date.

If the customer chooses "Delivery Date", a new field appears with the date and time of delivery. That's about how [here](https://s3.envato.com/files/252568265/screenshot/get-extra-field.png)

Based on *"[Enable Datepicker in a WooCommerce Checkout custom text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045814/enable-datepicker-in-a-woocommerce-checkout-custom-text-field/47049009#47049009)"* answer code, I made additional fields for the date and time of delivery, "ASAP" and "Delivery Date". I downloaded DateTimePicker from [here](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/).

Here is my code:

```
// Register main datetimepicker jQuery plugin script
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enabling_date_time_picker' );
function enabling_date_time_picker() {

// Only on front-end and checkout page
if( is_admin() || ! is_checkout() ) return;

// Load the datetimepicker jQuery-ui plugin script
    wp_enqueue_style( 'datetimepicker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css', array());
    wp_enqueue_script('datetimepicker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js', array());

}

// Call datetimepicker functionality in your custom text field
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field', 10, 1);

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

date_default_timezone_set('Europe');
$mydateoptions = array('' => __('', 'woocommerce' ));

echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">
<h3>'.__('Delivery Info').'</h3>';

echo '
<script>

    jQuery(function($){
        $("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker({format:\'d.m.Y H:i\', allowTimes:[
        \'11:00\', \'11:30\', \'12:00\', \'12:30\', \'13:00\', \'13:30\', \'14:00\', \'14:30\',
        \'15:00\', \'15:30\', \'16:00\', \'16:30\', \'17:00\', \'17:30\', \'18:00\', \'18:30\',
        \'19:00\', \'19:30\', \'20:00\', \'20:30\', \'21:00\', \'21:30\', \'22:00\', \'22:30\']
        });
    });
</script>';

// Checkbox ASAP
woocommerce_form_field( 'order_delivery_asap', array(
'type'          => 'checkbox',
'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
'label'         => __('As Soon As Possible'),
'checked'       => '',
'default'       => 0,
), $checkout->get_value( 'order_delivery_asap' ));


// Checkbox Delivery Date
woocommerce_form_field( 'order_delivery_date', array(
'type'          => 'checkbox',
'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
'label'         => __('Delivery Date'),
'checked'       => '',
'default'       => 0,
), $checkout->get_value( 'order_delivery_date' ));

// DateTimePicker
woocommerce_form_field( 'order_pickup_date', array(
    'type'          => 'text',
    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'id'            => 'datetimepicker',
    'required'      => false,
    'label'         => __('Select date'),
    'placeholder'   => __(''),
    'options'       => $mydateoptions
    ),$checkout->get_value( 'order_pickup_date' ));         

echo '</div>';
}
```

As I understand it, I need to include conditional logic here so that when selecting the "Delivery Date" checkbox, a field with a DateTimePicker appears. And so that the selected values of the ASAP checkbox and DateTimePicker are saved.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to do all this correctly. 
I will be glad for your help!

Comment: You say *"You need to add these fields"*, you mean may be ***"I need…"***? … What means *"I made a conclusion of these fields on the order editing page."*. You should try to reword the part after your code as it's not clear (or understandable). Also your question is huge (too broad). You should try to split it into small question, if you don't want this to be "on hold" as too broad.

Comment: Sorry, I did the wrong thing. I updated the question and my cod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update with an addition** - The following code will:

- show / hide the date-time picker field depending on the selected checkbox…
- process the date field, checking that is not empty when visible
- save the selected option and the chosen date time (if the option is selected)

I have revisited your code changing your field slugs and adding some additional things.

**1) With Checkboxes**

```
// Register main datetimepicker jQuery plugin script
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enabling_date_time_picker' );
function enabling_date_time_picker() {

    // Only on front-end and checkout page
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :

    // Load the datetimepicker jQuery-ui plugin script
    wp_enqueue_style( 'datetimepicker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css', array());
    wp_enqueue_script('datetimepicker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', false );
    endif;
}

// Display custom checkout fields (+ datetime picker)
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'display_custom_checkout_fields', 10, 1 );
function display_custom_checkout_fields( $checkout ) {
    // Define the time zone
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris'); // <== Set the time zone (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">
    <h3>'.__('Delivery Info').'</h3>';

    // Hide datetimepicker container field
    echo'<style> #datetimepicker_field.off { display:none; } </style>';

    // Checkbox ASAP
    woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_asap', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __("As Soon As Possible", "woocommerce"),
        'checked'       => '',
        'default'       => 0,
    ), '');


    // Checkbox Delivery Date
    woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_option', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __("Choose a delivery Date", "woocommerce"),
        'checked'       => '',
        'default'       => 0,
    ), '');

    // DateTimePicker
    woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_date', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide off'),
        'id'            => 'datetimepicker',
        'required'      => false,
        'label'         => __('Select date'),
        'placeholder'   => __(''),
        'options'       => array('' => __('', 'woocommerce' ))
    ),'');

    echo '</div>';
}

// The jQuery script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'checkout_delivery_jquery_script');
function checkout_delivery_jquery_script() {
    // Only on front-end and checkout page
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :

    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        var a = 'input[name="delivery_asap"]',
            c = 'input[name="delivery_option"]',
            d = '#datetimepicker',
            f = d+'_field';

        $(f).hide();
        $(a).prop('checked', true);

        // First checkbox
        $(a).change(function(){
            if( $(this).prop('checked') == true ){
                $(f).hide();
                $(c).prop('checked', false);
            } else {
                $(f).show();
                $(c).prop('checked', true);
            }
        });

        // Second checkbox
        $(c).change(function(){
            if( $(this).prop('checked') == true ){
                $(f).show();
                $(a).prop('checked', false);
            } else {
                $(f).hide();
                $(a).prop('checked', true);
            }
        });

        $(d).datetimepicker({
            format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
            allowTimes:[ '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30',
                '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00', '17:30', '18:00', '18:30',
                '19:00', '19:30', '20:00', '20:30', '21:00', '21:30', '22:00', '22:30']
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php

    endif;
}

// Check that the delivery date is not empty when it's selected
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'check_datetimepicker_field' );
function check_datetimepicker_field() {
    if ( isset($_POST['delivery_option']) && empty($_POST['delivery_date']) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Error: You must choose a delivery date and time', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    }
}

// Check that the delivery date is not empty when it's selected
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_order_delivery_data', 10, 2 );
function save_order_delivery_data( $order, $data ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['delivery_option']) && $_POST['delivery_option'] && ! empty($_POST['delivery_date']) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_delivery_datetime', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['delivery_date'] ) );
        $order->update_meta_data( '_delivery_option', 'date' );
    } elseif( isset($_POST['delivery_asap']) && $_POST['delivery_asap'] ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_delivery_option', 'azap' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in `function.php` file of your active child theme *(or active theme)*. Tested and works.

---

**2) *Addition* with radio buttons**

It might be better to replace the checkboxes by radio buttons:

```
// Register main datetimepicker jQuery plugin script
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enabling_date_time_picker' );
function enabling_date_time_picker() {

    // Only on front-end and checkout page
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :

    // Load the datetimepicker jQuery-ui plugin script
    wp_enqueue_style( 'datetimepicker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css', array());
    wp_enqueue_script('datetimepicker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', false );
    endif;
}

// Display custom checkout fields (+ datetime picker)
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'display_custom_checkout_fields', 10, 1 );
function display_custom_checkout_fields( $checkout ) {
    // Define the time zone
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris'); // <== Set the time zone (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">
    <h3>'.__('Delivery Info').'</h3>';

    // Hide datetimepicker container field
    echo'<style> #datetimepicker_field.off { display:none; } </style>';

    // Radio buttons field: Selected option
    woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_option', array(
        'type'      => 'radio',
        'class'     => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'options'   => array(
            'asap'  => __('As Soon As Possible'),
            'date'  => __('Select Delivery Date'),
        ),
    ), 'asap' );

    // DateTimePicker
    woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_date', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide off'),
        'id'            => 'datetimepicker',
        'required'      => false,
        'label'         => __('Select date'),
        'placeholder'   => __(''),
        'options'       => array('' => __('', 'woocommerce' ))
    ),'');

    echo '</div>';
}

// The jQuery script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'checkout_delivery_jquery_script');
function checkout_delivery_jquery_script() {
    // Only on front-end and checkout page
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :

    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        var d = '#datetimepicker',
            f = d+'_field',
            r = 'input[name="delivery_option"]';

        $(f).hide();

        // On radio button change
        $(r).change(function(){
            if( $(this).val() == 'date' ){
                $(f).show();
            } else {
                $(f).hide();
            }
        });

        // Enable the datetime picker field
        $(d).datetimepicker({
            format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
            allowTimes:[ '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30',
                '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00', '17:30', '18:00', '18:30',
                '19:00', '19:30', '20:00', '20:30', '21:00', '21:30', '22:00', '22:30']
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php

    endif;
}

// Check that the delivery date is not empty when it's selected
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'check_datetimepicker_field' );
function check_datetimepicker_field() {
    if ( isset($_POST['delivery_option']) && $_POST['delivery_option'] === 'date'
    && isset($_POST['delivery_date']) && empty($_POST['delivery_date']) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Error: You must choose a delivery date and time', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    }
}

// Check that the delivery date is not empty when it's selected
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_order_delivery_data', 10, 2 );
function save_order_delivery_data( $order, $data ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['delivery_option']) && $_POST['delivery_option'] == 'date' && ! empty($_POST['delivery_date']) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_delivery_datetime', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['delivery_date'] ) );
    }
    if( isset($_POST['delivery_option']) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_delivery_option', esc_attr( $_POST['delivery_option'] ) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in `function.php` file of your active child theme *(or active theme)*. Tested and works.

---

#### Get your delivery custom fields values

To get your delivery custom fields values, you will use:

1) From `$order`, `WC_Order` Object (using `WC_Data` `get_meta()` method):

```
$delivery_option = $order->get_meta('_delivery_option');

if( $delivery_option == 'date' ) {
    $delivery_datetime = $order->get_meta('_delivery_datetime');
}
```

2) From `$order_id`, the order ID (using WordPress `get_post_meta()` function)

```
$delivery_option = get_post_meta($order_id, '_delivery_option', true);

if( $delivery_option == 'date' ) {
    $delivery_datetime = get_post_meta($order_id, '_delivery_datetime', true);
}
```

> **The following:** [Display custom fields values in WooCommerce order and email notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55115256/display-custom-fields-values-in-woocommerce-order-and-email-notification)

---

**Related thread:** [Enable Datepicker in a WooCommerce Checkout custom text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045814/enable-datepicker-in-a-woocommerce-checkout-custom-text-field/47049009#47049009)

Comment: Many thanks for the answer and help! Your code works great. And you're right, it's better to make a radio button. Just the checkbox gives the values 0 or 1. What will the radio button look like in your code?

Comment: To put a radio button, I just need to replace the 'type' => 'radio', ? To save and display values, something needs to be changed? What will the radio button look like in your code?

Comment: The code will be quiet different… I will make an addition for radio buttons later.

Comment: Thank You for help!

Comment: @Dmitry You got it with radios !

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use radio buttons instead

```
woocommerce_form_field( 'order_delivery_method', array(
    'type'          => 'radio',
    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'options'       => array(
            'method_asap' => __('As Soon As Possible'),
            'method_date' => __('Select Delivery Date'),
    ),
), $checkout->get_value('order_delivery_method'));


woocommerce_form_field( 'order_delivery_date', array(
    'id'            => 'DeliveryDatePicker',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'label'         => __('Delivery Date'),
    'default'       => 0,
), $checkout->get_value( 'order_delivery_date' ));
```

and append javascript with

```
$("#DeliveryDatePicker").hide();
$("input[name='order_delivery_method']").click(function () {
    if($(this).val() == 'method_date') {
        $("#DeliveryDatePicker").show();
    } else {
        $("#DeliveryDatePicker").hide();
    }
});
```

There will be two radio buttons, if someone chooses Exact Date, dateform field will be shown.

Edit, Full Version:

```
// Register main datetimepicker jQuery plugin script
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enabling_date_time_picker' );
function enabling_date_time_picker() {

// Only on front-end and checkout page
if( is_admin() || ! is_checkout() ) return;

// Load the datetimepicker jQuery-ui plugin script
    wp_enqueue_style( 'datetimepicker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css', array());
    wp_enqueue_script('datetimepicker', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js', array());

}

// Call datetimepicker functionality in your custom text field
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field', 10, 1);

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

date_default_timezone_set('Europe');
$mydateoptions = array('' => __('', 'woocommerce' ));

echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">
<h3>'.__('Delivery Info').'</h3>';

echo '
<script>
    $("#DeliveryDatePicker").hide();
    $("input[name=\'order_delivery_method\']").click(function () {
        if($(this).val() == 'method_date') {
            $("#DeliveryDatePicker").show();
        } else {
            $("#DeliveryDatePicker").hide();
        }
    });
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#DeliveryDatePicker").datetimepicker({format:\'d.m.Y H:i\', allowTimes:[
        \'11:00\', \'11:30\', \'12:00\', \'12:30\', \'13:00\', \'13:30\', \'14:00\', \'14:30\',
        \'15:00\', \'15:30\', \'16:00\', \'16:30\', \'17:00\', \'17:30\', \'18:00\', \'18:30\',
        \'19:00\', \'19:30\', \'20:00\', \'20:30\', \'21:00\', \'21:30\', \'22:00\', \'22:30\']
        });
    });
</script>';

woocommerce_form_field( 'order_delivery_method', array(
    'type'          => 'radio',
    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'options'       => array(
            'method_asap' => __('As Soon As Possible'),
            'method_date' => __('Select Delivery Date'),
    ),
), $checkout->get_value('order_delivery_method'));


woocommerce_form_field( 'order_delivery_date', array(
    'id'            => 'DeliveryDatePicker',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'label'         => __('Delivery Date'),
    'default'       => 0,
), $checkout->get_value( 'order_delivery_date' ));       

echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Strange, posted your code, but the radio button is not shown at all.

Can you show what my code should be? All code, please.

And last, how can you put these fields after choosing a delivery method?

Comment: I have updated code, try now, just replace all 3 `woocommerce_form_field` with my code and add javascript code after `<script>` tag, see full version in my Edit

Comment: The script produces the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'order_delivery_method' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' ".

Comment: The date field has id = "datetimepicker", and you have id = "DeliveryDatePicker"

Comment: woocommerce_form_field acceps 3 parameters, key, argumens and value, everything is set correctly, are you sure that you have placed everything correctly ?
or specify exactly on which line is  error

Comment: error here '$("input[name='order_delivery_method']").click(function () {'

Comment: My date field has id = "datetimepicker", and you have id = "DeliveryDatePicker". Therefore, the datetimepicker does not work.

Comment: @Dmitry I don't think that it's because of different ID, but change it if you want, error was because or brackets, I have edited final code, try now

Comment: Your code again gives an error. Excuse me, but I will give an accept to the second answer.