# Display custom fields values in WooCommerce order and email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

Based on "[Choosing a date and time after choosing the WooCommerce delivery method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886638/choosing-a-date-and-time-after-choosing-the-woocommerce-delivery-method/54993788#54993788)" answer code, that displays custom Pickup fields and delivery dates, the following code displays the delivery data of those fields on the order edit pages.

Here is my code:

```
// View fields in Edit Order Page
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_fields_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_fields_order_meta($order){   

    $delivery_option = $order->get_meta('_delivery_option');

    if( $delivery_option == 'date' ) {
    $delivery_datetime = $order->get_meta('_delivery_datetime');

    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Delivery').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, '_delivery_option', true ) . '</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Delivery Date').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, '_delivery_datetime', true ) . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, only the delivery date that the customer chooses is displayed correctly, and the options of the radio button "As Soon As Possible" are not shown.

Apparently, I'm doing something wrong.

I would like also to display these fields values on the Thank You page and in the email.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the custom fields values in backend order edit pages *(if they are saved in database for the order)*, use the following:

```
// View fields in Edit Order Page
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_custom_fields_value_admin_order', 10, 1 );
function display_custom_fields_value_admin_order( $order ){
    // Display the delivery option
    if( $delivery_option =  $order->get_meta('_delivery_option') )
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Delivery type').':</strong> ' . $delivery_option . '</p>';

    // Display the delivery date
    if( $delivery_datetime = $order->get_meta('_delivery_datetime') )
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Delivery Date').':</strong> ' . $delivery_datetime . '</p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

The best shorter clean way to display the custom field values everywhere on **frontend order pages** and **on email notifications** is to display them in order totals table, just like used payment methods:

```
// Display the chosen delivery information
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'chosen_delivery_item_order_totals', 10, 3 );
function chosen_delivery_item_order_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {;
    $new_total_rows = [];

    // Loop through Order total lines
    foreach($total_rows as $key => $total ){
        // Get the chosen delivery values
        $delivery_option  = $order->get_meta('_delivery_option');
        $delivery_datetime = $order->get_meta('_delivery_datetime');

        // Display delivery information before payment method
        if( ! empty($delivery_option) && 'payment_method' === $key ){
            $label  = empty($delivery_datetime) ? __('Delivery') : __('Delivery Date');
            $value  = empty($delivery_datetime) ? __('AZAP', $domain) : $delivery_datetime;

            // Display 'Delivery method' line
            $new_total_rows['chosen_delivery'] = array( 'label' => $label,'value' => $value );
        }
        $new_total_rows[$key] = $total;
    }

    return $new_total_rows;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

**Related thread:** [Choosing a date and time after choosing the WooCommerce delivery method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886638/choosing-a-date-and-time-after-choosing-the-woocommerce-delivery-method/54993788#54993788)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Your code works great. On the order edit page shows "Delivery type: date". How can I change, for example, the word "by the time"?

Comment: @Dmitry Which word "by the time"?

Comment: Is it possible to change the "date" and set "by a certain time"?

Comment: @Dmitry so instead of the displayed date you want the sentence "by a certain time"… where in admin or in frontend + emails?

Comment: So in the first code snippet in last line inside the function, you replace `$delivery_datetime` by `__("by a certain time")`